# Datatable Javascript Link not working on 2nd page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a list of data in a table and am using the dataTable plugin for pagination.

However, my last column is a link. When I go to the 2nd page I cannot click the link, but the link opens only on the first page of the table.

When I did not have the datatable all the linked work, but it was when i added this it didnt work...

My code:

```
 <table id="PartsResultListGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartsRequestOrderNum)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Call_Num)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DetailView)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartsRequestOrderNum)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Call_Num)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div data-callno='@item.PartsRequestOrderNum' data-url="@Url.Action("GetPartsInfo", "Parts")">
                        <div class="PartsViewSubmit toolbarIcon">
                            <div class="toolbarIconText">View</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PartsResultListGrid').dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
    });
});
</script>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

My ajax link inside this which opens the link:

```
        $('.PartsViewSubmit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).parent().data("url"),
            data: { PartsRequestOrderNum: $(this).parent().data("callno") },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#PartsDetail").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: You probably have some javascript / jquery that populate those links. It is fired once, eg not working on live content, and therefore does the links not work on page #2, since those rows where not visible at the time your link population was executed.

Comment: yes i do, iv updated my code showing the link, so what will i need to do to get it working on the 2nd page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [**delegated event**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) :

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

So in your case, I would do this instead :

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.PartsViewSubmit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```